# How Many Times Would The Assembler Load and Store i

Tags: assembly

So, this is a snippet of a C code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    a[i] = rand() & 0xFF;
    printf("a[%d]: %d\n", i, a[i]);
}
```

Now, imagine "i" is a local variable stored in the stack. How many times would "i" be called from the stack for each iteration? Is it:

> A. Once at the beginning of the loop

or

> B. Three times: once at the beginning, once for assigning the value of a[i] and once for the printf function (I assume that they are all stored back to the stack immediately after they are used in this case)

I think it is A but I fear I am thinking about it in terms of what would be optimal and not what the assembler may actually do.

Comment: Have you already tried looking at the actual output generated by a C compiler?
There's a neat [online tool](https://godbolt.org/) you can use to compare the assembly generated by different compilers.

Comment: @Knogger It keeps saying that the compilation failed

Comment: @Knogger Never mind. That answered my question. Thank you very much

Comment: For others to profit from your question and insight, you are welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer).

Comment: @greybeard That seems like a good idea. I think I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer uses ARMv8 AArch64 Assembly (ARM64)**

```
.LC0:
        .string "a[%d]: %d\n"
square:                            
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -128]!
        mov     x29, sp
        str     w0, [sp, 28]
        mov     w0, 1         (A)
        str     w0, [sp, 124] (B)
        b       .L2
.L3:
        bl      rand
        and     w2, w0, 255
        ldrsw   x0, [sp, 124]  (a)
        lsl     x0, x0, 2
        add     x1, sp, 40
        str     w2, [x1, x0]
        ldrsw   x0, [sp, 124] <b>
        lsl     x0, x0, 2
        add     x1, sp, 40
        ldr     w0, [x1, x0]
        mov     w2, w0
        ldr     w1, [sp, 124] <c>
        adrp    x0, .LC0
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:.LC0
        bl      printf
        ldr     w0, [sp, 124] (d)
        add     w0, w0, 1
        str     w0, [sp, 124]
.L2:
        ldr     w0, [sp, 124]
        cmp     w0, 4
        ble     .L3
        ldr     w0, [sp, 28]
        mul     w0, w0, w0
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 128
        ret
```

The correct answer here is B. In the compiled code above, it is obvious that (A) and (B) is where the value "i" is moved into a register. If you take note of the address where it is stored [sp, 124], you will see that it is loaded in 3 scenarios (although one of the scenarios requires it to be loaded twice - <b> and <c>).

The first scenario in which it was loaded was when the program initialized a[i] (a). The second scenario was when it was called twice for the `printf()` function and the third time was when it was called to be incremented as part of the loop.

It is also worthy to note that the compiler actually only adds a store instruction for a loaded value if it has been changed (I did not know that).

It may be a bit hard to see because it is not color-coded here but you can use this tool called [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) that color codes each line so you know exactly what is happening (you can select other Assembly Languages to generate and display).

Finally, a huge thanks to @Knogger for telling me about the Compiler Explorer. Huge help!

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by “load” and “store”? Accessing memory?

An optimising compiler will assign i to a register. Compilers for modern CPUs with many registers will expect that some set of registers are either not modified or restored by the callee, so i within a register will survive the calls to rand and printf in a register.

So i will not be loaded or stored at all. The register that i is allocated to is saved at the start and restored at the end of the function, assuming an optimising compiler. And a non-optimising compiler doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate gnasher729’s answer, here is how the snippet is compiled by gcc. As you can see, the value of `i` is kept in register `rbx` and never written to memory (no space is even allocated to it on the stack). The only memory stores are to `a[i]` (which I made a global variable; I’m not sure that was the intent in the incomplete C code, but whatever. If it is made local, the comiler optimizes it away completely as its values are never used again.):

```
LC0:
        .string "a[%d]: %d\n"
        .text
        .p2align 4
        .globl  f
        .type   f, @function
f:
.LFB39:
        .cfi_startproc
        endbr64
        pushq   %r12
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 12, -16
        leaq    a(%rip), %r12
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
        .cfi_offset 6, -24
        leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rbp
        pushq   %rbx
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
        .cfi_offset 3, -32
        xorl    %ebx, %ebx
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L2:
        call    rand@PLT
        movl    %ebx, %edx
        movq    %rbp, %rsi
        movl    $1, %edi
        movzbl  %al, %ecx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    %ecx, (%r12,%rbx,4)
        addq    $1, %rbx
        call    __printf_chk@PLT
        cmpq    $20, %rbx
        jne     .L2
        popq    %rbx
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        popq    %r12
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```